# Get rows from column via sql injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

For a school project I need to hack a database (made by the school for practice) and I have to retrieve all the rows of a specific column via SQL-Injection. I have been provided the column and table name.

Here is my example query that needs help.

```
bla' union all select 2, DefaultCreditCardNumber,5,6 from buyer#
```

This will retrieve only 1 row each time I enter the query. Is it possible to get all the rows at once? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the queries results are not printed in a loop you can not get all rows at once.

You need to get the data row by row:

```
bla' union all select 2, DefaultCreditCardNumber,5,6 from buyer LIMIT n,1#
```

Where n is the index of the row (0, 1, 2, ...)

Comment: thank you for the information ;), gues i have to do it row by row :S

Comment: It’s the other way round: `LIMIT n, 1` retrieves 1 row beginning at row *n*.